# Detecting a tremor given accelerometer data

Tags: time-series, computational-statistics, signal-processing, anomaly-detection, signal-detection

I'm trying to figure out what technique to use in order to detect a tremor in accelerometer data. I have the acceleration in the x, y and z coordinates. I've plotted 4 graphs of this data below with various degrees of tremor. The plots below show the data for 20 seconds in which the tremor occurred. Ideally, however, this algorithm would be able to detect no tremor in the top left figure, but could detect a tremor in the top right figure. And if the data in the top left figure and top right figure were concatenated, then it would detect the tremor only after the 20 second mark in the 40 seconds worth of concatenated data.

I've done a bit or research online and it seems that a technique from signal processing could be uesful here, but I'm not sure. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]